# System.InvalidOperationException - adding dynamic countdate

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have trying to provide many time counter, here is my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
long date=8000;
TextBlock tx = new TextBlock();
tx.Name="txt"+i;
CountDateLoad(date,tx);
grid.Children.Add(tx);
}
```

.

```
void CountDateLoad(long dt, TextBlock tx )
        {
            var countdownAnimation = new StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

            for (var i = dt; i > 0; i--)
            {
                var keyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(dt - i);
                string result = CountDate(i);
                var frame = new DiscreteStringKeyFrame(result, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(keyTime));
                countdownAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(frame);
            }
            countdownAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteStringKeyFrame(" ", KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6))));
           Storyboard.SetTargetName(tx.Name);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(countdownAnimation, new PropertyPath(TextBlock.TextProperty));

            var countdownStoryboard = new Storyboard();
            countdownStoryboard.Children.Add(countdownAnimation);
            //  countdownStoryboard.Completed += CountdownTimer_Completed;

            countdownStoryboard.Begin(this);
        }


  private string CountDate(long p)
        {
            long hour = p / 3600;
            long minute = (p - (hour * 3600)) / 60;
            long second = p % 60;
            string result = "";
            if (hour < 10) result += "0";
            result += hour + " : ";
            if (minute < 10) result += "0";
            result += minute + " : ";
            if (second < 10) result += "0";
            result += second;
            return result;
        }
```

Here is the error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'txt0' name cannot be found in the name scope
>   of 'MainWindow'.

Comment: Use (someFrameworkElement).RegsiterName(Name,element), where someFrameworkElement is a scope. Here is sample: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167364/RegisterName-for-StoryBoards-in-WPF-NameScopes

Comment: @sTrenat working on it. please write it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `StoryBoard` tx.Name is not enough, you need to register your control (textbox) name in `Scope` that you want to use it in. For this you should go with `(someFrameworkElement).RegisterName(Name,element)`, where `someFrameworkElement` is a scope. Here is sample: [sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167364/RegisterName-for-StoryBoards-in-WPF-NameScopes), and msdn [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername(v=vs.110).aspx)